# How do I scroll to the correct item on the list in the left side when I click the back button in Nuxt?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, server-side-rendering, nuxt.js

- I have a List Detail View using Nuxt dynamic routes in SSR mode
- The list with overflow-y appears on left and on clicking an item, the contents appear on right
- When I click each item, the URL params change and a new item is shown on right
- When I press back button the previous item is shown but the scrollbar does not change
- How do I make the scrollbar go to the previous item?
- Here is the GIF showing the problem, on clicking back, the list should scroll to the previous item

[image]

```
<template>
  <div class="root">
    <div class="left">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="i in sortedArticles" :key="i.feedItemId">
          <nuxt-link :to="'/articles/' + i.feedItemId" :id="i.feedItemId" no-prefetch>{{ i.title }}</nuxt-link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right">Article {{ $route.params.id }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  key(route) {
    return 'articles'
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      sortedArticles: 'news/SORTED_ARTICLES'
    })
  },
}
</script>

<style>
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 1.8;
}
.root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100vh;
}
.left {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.left ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.left li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  color: black;
}
.left li a:hover {
  color: darkorange;
}

.right {
  flex: 1;
}
</style>
```

The above code is the pages/articles/_id.vue file
How do I achieve this in NUXT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be use `watch`:

```
<li :ref="'el' + i.feedItemId" v-for="i in sortedArticles" :key="i.feedItemId">
```

```
watch: {
    '$route.params.id': function(id) {
       this.$refs['el' + id].scrollIntoView()
    }
}
```